# Union two Lists of different types using a common property

Tags: c#, linq

I have two different list of objects with a common property, I'm trying to merge them into a single object,

I have

```
public class CustomerMRMetric
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<int, decimal> MRMetrics { get; set; }
    }

public class CustomerLRMetric
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<int, string> LRMetrics { get; set; }
    }
```

I get two separate lists of these objects, What should I do to get the following output?

```
public class CustomerMetrics
    {
        public Dictionary<int, decimal> MRMetrics { get; set; }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<int, string> LRMetrics { get; set; }
    }
```

I cannot do an inner join directly because a customerId can have value in one list but not in another and it's both the way around meaning either MRMetrics or LRMetrics can be null.

Comment: Are the inputs in memory / stored in a lookup? Could you union the IDs first and then iterate over them, do a lookup for each part and then form the result object? Are you guaranteed to have only max one of each object type for a given ID or do you need to Union the dictionary too?

Comment: Unioning the customerIds and then iterating over them and doing a lookup works! Would there be a significant performance issue doing this way?

Comment: You'd need to test performance, it might be faster as you would only be allocating a result once and never having to update it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var list1 = new List<CustomerMRMetric>();
    var list2 = new List<CustomerLRMetric>();
    var left = list1.Select(l1 => new CustomerMetrics
    {
        CustomerId = l1.CustomerId,
        MRMetrics = l1.MRMetrics,
        LRMetrics = list2.FirstOrDefault(l2 => l2.CustomerId == l1.CustomerId)?.LRMetrics
    });
    var right = list2.Select(l2 => new CustomerMetrics
    {
        CustomerId = l2.CustomerId,
        LRMetrics = l2.LRMetrics,
        MRMetrics = list1.FirstOrDefault(l1 => l1.CustomerId == l2.CustomerId)?.MRMetrics
    });
    var inner = list1.Join(list2, l1 => l1.CustomerId, l2 => l2.CustomerId, (l1, l2) => new CustomerMetrics
    {
        CustomerId = l1.CustomerId,
        MRMetrics = l1.MRMetrics,
        LRMetrics = l2.LRMetrics
    });
    var union = left.Concat(inner).Concat(right);
}
public class CustomerMRMetric
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, decimal> MRMetrics { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerLRMetric
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, string> LRMetrics { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerMetrics
{
    public Dictionary<int, decimal> MRMetrics { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, string> LRMetrics { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that this code hasn't been tested.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentDictionary includes a useful `AddOrUpdate` method which you could use like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, CustomerMetrics> combined = 
  new ConcurrentDictionary<int, CustomerMetrics>();
    
List<CustomerMRMetric> source1 = new List<CustomerMRMetric>();
List<CustomerLRMetric> source2 = new List<CustomerLRMetric>();

foreach (var s1 in source1) 
  combined.AddOrUpdate(s1.CustomerId, 
    key => new CustomerMetrics(){ CustomerId = key, MRMetrics = s1.MRMetrics },
    (key, v) => new CustomerMetrics() { CustomerId = key, MRMetrics = s1.MRMetrics });

foreach (var s2 in source2) 
  combined.AddOrUpdate(s2.CustomerId, 
    key => new CustomerMetrics(){ CustomerId = key, LRMetrics = s2.LRMetrics },
    (key, v) => new CustomerMetrics() { CustomerId = key, 
        MRMetrics = v.MRMetrics, LRMetrics = s2.LRMetrics });
```

And that gives you opportunities to handle duplicates too if they exist in either input source.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot do an inner join directly because a customerId can have value in one list but not in another

You are right. What you do need is a `full outer join`: all elements from the left that has no right, all elements from the right that has no left and all elements that are in left and right.

I could give you a solution suitable only for this problem, programming is much more fun if I make a reusable solution.

I'll make an extension method for a full outer join, for two different sequences with property selectors, similar to inner join. If you are not familiar with extension methods, visit [Extension Methods Demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<T1, T2, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> leftSequence,
    IEnumerable<T2> rightSequence,
    Func<T1, TKey> leftKeySelector,
    Func<T2, TKey> rightKeySelector,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return FullOuterJoin(leftSequence, rightSequence,
        leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector,
        resultSelector, null);
}

public IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<T1, T2, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> leftSequence,
    IEnumerable<T2> rightSequence,
    Func<T1, TKey> leftKeySelector,
    Func<T2, TKey> rightKeySelector,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>, TResult> resultSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    // TODO: check inputs not null
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    // TODO: implement
}
```

Usage will be:

```
IEnumerable<CustomerMRMetric> customerMRMetrics = ...
IEnumerable<CustomerLRMetric> customerLRMetrics = ...

IEnumerable<CustomerMetric> customerMetrics = customerMRMetrics.LeftOuterJoin(
    customerLRMetrics,

    mrMetric => mrMetric.CustomerId,   // from every mrMetric take the CustomerId
    lrMetric => lrMetric.CustomerId,   // from every lrMetric take the CustomerId

    // parameter resultSelector: from every used CustomerIds,
    // and all zero or more mrMetrics with this CustomerId,
    // and all zero or more lrMetrics with this CustomerId,
    // construct one new CustomerMetric:
    (customerId, mrMetricsWithThisCustomerId, lrMetricsWithThisCustomerId) => new CustomerMetric
    {
        CustomerId = customerId,
        MrMetrics = mrMetricsWithThisCustomerId.MrMetrics,
        LRMetrics = lrMetricsWithThisCustomerId.LrMetrics,
    });
```

Note: just like in a full inner join, the item that you join upon, doesn't have to be the same property. For instance, if you want to give Customers who Order something on their Birthday, you can join left on `Customer.BirthDate`, and right on `Order.OrderDate`. Of course, even though the *names* of the keys don't have to be the same, the *type* of both properties do have to be the same, otherwise you can't compare for equality.

Well, if this is a little bit what you want, let's implement the extension method!

### The implementation

You didn't say that every CustomerId is unique. In your case it will probably be, but if you want to do a FullOuterJoin on for instance Customer.City, then the key will probably not be unique.

First we make two `LookupTables`: From all elements in Left, we make a LookupTable with the Tkey from leftKeySelector as keys. From all elements in right, we make a LookupTable with the Tkey from rightKeySelector as keys.

Then we get all used Keys from both lookupTables. We need a Distinct to remove duplicate keys that are both in left and right.

Then we enumerate all these unique keys. We search in the left lookup and in the right lookup.

Note: if a key is not used in the Left sequence, then the search will return an empty collection, meaning that left has no elements with this key This has the advantage that we are certain that we don't have to worry about NULL. Of course similar for right. If the key is in both left and right, both searches will return a non-empty sequence.

The implementation of the full outer join:

```
// TODO: check inputs not null
if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

var leftLookup = leftSequence.ToLookup(leftKeySelector, comparer);
var rightLookup = rightSequence.ToLookup(rightKeySelector, comparer);

var leftKeys = leftLookup.Select(left => left.Key);
var rightKeys = rightLookup.Select(right => right.Key);
var allUsedKeys = leftKeys.Concat(rightKeys).Distinct(comparer);

// enumerate all keys, fetch all items with this key from left, do the same from right
foreach (TKey key in allUsedKeys)
{
    IEnumerable<T1> leftItemsWithThisKey = leftLookup[key];
    IEnumerable<T2> rightItemsWithThisKey = rightLookup[key];
    TResult result = resultSelector(key, leftItemsWithThisKey, rightItemsWithThisKey);
    yield return result;
}
```

Of course you can put several statements into one statement. This won't speed up the  process very much. However it will deteriorate readability.

Because I use yield return, the method uses deferred execution, just like most LINQ methods: no more Lookups are done than needed.

```
var result = customerMRMetrics.LeftOuterJoin(customerLRMetrics, ...)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will only do one lookup on the left lookup table, and one lookup on the right lookup table.

Of course, to construct the first return value, I need to do a lot:

- create the two lookup tables. This means that both input sequences are enumerated once.
- Both lookup tables are enumerated once to get all keys
- All keys are enumerated once to remove duplicates

So to create the first result item, a lot of work is needed. Luckily, for every next result item I don't need to do any enumeration on either left nor right. I only need  to do two Lookups, which is as fast as a lookup in a Dictionary.